# Derive Model from Another Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop, models

In my ASP.Net MVC 3 project, I'd like to have a base class model object that has certain properties that I will then use in all of the other models in my application (or at least most of them).  That way, the views that use these derived models will also have the base class model properties.

The base class model properties could be set in, say a base class controller, and then somehow I need to populate the derived models with that same data.  Any suggestions on how to best get 'er done?

Or should I be looking into creating my own DefaultModelBinder somehow?  I'm a little confused as to my options here.  As if you couldn't tell. :)

**Sample Code**

*Base Model*

```
public class ElkModel
{
    public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }
}
```

*Derived Model*

```
public class UserModel : ElkModel
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public int User_ID { get; set; }

    // Other properties specific to this model
}
```

*So in the base controller*

```
private BaseModel baseModel;

protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    baseModel = new baseModel();
    baseModel.MyProperty = "test";

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

*And in the derived controller action method*

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Derives from the base model in the base controller
    UserModel model = new UserModel();

    // model.IsAdministrator where IsAdministrator is a property of the base Model not UserModel

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need this 'common data' across all views, I would not throw inheritance in the mix.
I would go for an extension method.

Something along the lines of:

```
public static CommonData GetCommonData(this HtmlHelper htmlhelper)
        {
            // do your magic here
        }
```

In your View you could then simply call:

```
@Html.GetCommonData()...
```

That way you keep your models cleaner.

Inheritance might be a valid approach, if this Common Data really 'fits' well with your Model classes.

It would help if you provided some examples ;-)

** EDIT **

I would keep your 'BaseModel' as a property in the Controller and populate it on OnActionExecuting as you suggest.

But I would use ExtensionMethods on the Controller and Html helper to access the the data.
If you use inheritance you will needlessly complicate things.

Let me know if you need samples of the extension methods.

This approach is DRY. You are not duplicating code.

** EDIT 2 **

Here is how your extension method should look like: (off the top of my head, so it might not compile)

```
public static class ExtensionHelpers
{
    public static BaseModel GetCommonData(this HtmlHelper htmlhelper)
    {
        YourController HtmlHelper = htmlhelper.ViewContext.Controller as YourController;
        if (controller != null)
        {
            return HtmlHelper.BaseModel;
        }
        return null;
}
```

Make sure the Controller derives from the Controller class where you add the BaseModel property. I called it 'YourController' above.

Then you should be good to go ;-)

Edit 3

Just a reminder that the namespace needs to be known if you want to use extension methods in a View.
The best way to achieve this is to include the namespace in the Web.Config in your Views folder.

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Yournamespace" /> <- LOOK HERE
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: I know, I know... I couldn't think of any useful example at the time.  I think I've addressed it well though in my recent updating above.  The bottom line is that I need to access strongly typed properties on most of my models but in the spirit of DRY, I wanted to keep the code to populate those properties in one place (a base controller, I think).

Comment: Added even more detail (I hope) in my initial posting. Thanks for the gentle reminder.

Comment: If I used the approach you (initially) recommended, and I hit the database to pull these common properties, what would happen if I called the same property, say, 10 times in one View?  Then I'd hit the database 10 times, right?

Comment: NO! If implemented correctly you would hit the database only once.
You would populate the data in your Contoller Property in OnActionExecuting.
The database will not be hit again, regardless of how many times you call the Property

Comment: Interesting approach.  I'll look into it.  Thanks.  I'll respond back when I get a working solution.

Comment: I think I better ask you to supply some samples for the Extension methods.  I don't see/understand how I can retrieve the populated base model (which will be populated in the OnActionExecuting method) and use it in an Extension method which can then be used in the View.

Answer (score 1):

Depends a little on if you're talking about the incoming model or the outgoing model (i.e. the viewmodel served up or the model param being posted by a form).

In the former case, it's pretty easy to do it as you suggested; via a base controller that populates the model w/ the common info before or after the action executes (overriding OnActionExecuting or OnActionExecuted).  You can also use an ActionFilter which may be more flexible in that it doesn't require you to follow one inheritance chain for all your controllers.  I tend to recommend the latter approach for that very reason.

On the form post side, you may need to create your own Model Binder, but only if you have some reason you want to have a single action take in more than one type of the model, and frankly that could get hairy.  In that case you'd have to have the actual type name be put into a hidden form elemetn or something so that your model binder can ascertain which model to instantiate. I'd recommend against this approach unless you have a compelling reason for it.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the fast response.  I think we are only dealing with input Model/ViewModels here.  I'd be using the base model properties to trigger certain displays on the page (i.e. Model.IsAdministrator, for example).

Comment: OK, so I understand how I'd use, say, an overridden (is that a word?) OnActionExecuting method in base controller.  I'd have a model class as a private member to this controller and populate it's properties accordingly.  How would I get the base model properties into my model that derives from it.  See my updated code sample above in the original question.

Comment: Well, for this I think the easiest is actually to use OnActionExecuted, because then you can just extract the model from the ActionResult that's part of the filterContext parameter.  That way, if it's not a ViewResult, you save yourself looking up the data that you don't need.  As for getting the data, you get it like anything else, have your base controller have some reference (through injection or constructor params) to your data access layer, and it can query for the info.  Or if the info is derived, derive it.